# efficient way to insert the data from Access to csv file

Tags: c#

I am trying to insert data from access database to .csv file in C#. I have 54744 records in Access database. Inserting the records in CSV file is taking more than 2 hours. Below is my code:

```
 public void CreateCSVFile()
        {
            DataSet dsRecLoad = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("RecsCDDt");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("AccessConnection")))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from RecsCD", connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);
                    dt.Load(reader);

                }
            }

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                   foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sb.ToString()))
                            sb.Append(",");
                       sb.Append(row[dc.ColumnName].ToString());

                   }

                    sb.Append("\n");
                }

                string CSVfilePath = _configuration.GetValue<string>("MySettings:CSVFile");
                if (!File.Exists(CSVfilePath))
                {

                    File.WriteAllText(CSVfilePath, sb.ToString()) ;
                }


        }
```

Can anyone suggest me a more efficient way to insert the records in .CSV file.

Thank You.

Comment: Use a library where you can stream the results to a file, instead if writing the file in a big chunk. It will also help you to escape values and do other stuff that you're not taking care of at the moment: You can probably also stream the results from the reader, instead of loading the entire table into memory: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a small example of how you might achieve the same thing by streaming the data using a reader and writing to the file as a stream (untested):

```
await using var textWriter = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv");
await using var writer = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(textWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

await using var connection = new SqlConnection("connection_string");
await using var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from RecsCD", connection);
await connection.OpenAsync();
await using var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

while (await reader.ReadAsync()) {
    foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)) {
        writer.WriteField(await reader.GetFieldValueAsync<object>(i));
    }

    await writer.NextRecordAsync();
}
await writer.FlushAsync();
```

Note that the code depends on the [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) library.

Comment: For this particular scenario, not a great deal, except for handling escaping/line endings. It gets more useful if you have some pre-defined list of objects you want to serialize. Also the library helps with doing the reverse (reading csv files and mapping them to objects).

Comment: Sorry! I tried to pull my comment as quickly as I could because I just noticed your comment above which explained some of the advantages of CsvHelper. Thanks for the very fast response. Here is my original comment (question) for reference: "I've never used the CsvHelper library, so out of curiosity what does this library do in this scenario that makes it so useful. Thanks!"

Comment: Thanks Evan, my code is executing in less than 5 minutes.